# Convert charset name to NSStringEncoding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, character-encoding

Given a charset string, such as "utf-8", "iso-8859-1", "us-ascii" etc, is there any built-in way to get the appropriate NSStringEncoding in Cocoa?

Right now I'm looking at just building a NSDictionary containing a canonicalized version of the name mapped to the NSStringEncoding, then having a lookup mechanism that canonicalizes the input in the same way.  But is there really no way to get NSUTF8StringEncoding given the string "UTF-8", etc?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to go through CoreFoundation.

```
CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding
CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding
```

First converting the IANA Char set to CFStringEncoding value (Which is not the same as NSStringEncoding) and then convert the CFStringEncoding to NSStringEncoding.

```
NSString *encodingString = @"utf-8"
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef) encodingString));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSStringEncoding utfEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
NSLog(@"%lu",utfEncoding);

NSString * utf8Name = @"UTF-8";
CFStringEncoding aEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)utf8Name);
utfEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(aEncoding);
NSLog(@"%lu",utfEncoding);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any built-in way of achieving this. I think what you suggest - building a dictionary with the values - is a sensible way to go here. There aren't that many encodings so it should be quite trivial, and probably quicker than trying to find a  built-in way of doing it.